# How to solve for matrix $C$ in $A=BC-CB$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Given two positive matrices $A$ and $B$, such that $A = BC - CB$ for some matrix $C$. Is there any way of expressing $C$ in terms of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Assume $A,B,C$ are square matrices, then $A = BC-CB \implies {\rm Tr}(A) = {\rm Tr}(BC-CB) = 0$. How can a positive matrix has zero trace???

Comment: @achillehui The expression on the right side only is valid if $B$ and $C$ are square matrices with the same size, implying that $A$ is also a square matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There can be no general way of solving this for $C$. If e.g. $B = I$ is the identity-matrix then $A = 0$ for every $C$, so no information on $C$ can be obtained.

Comment: A is assumed to be positive, whatever this means, it should rule out the case $A=0$.